# Изолированный HTML контейнер

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли без фрейма создать div блок, в который можно поместить html код с неизвестными style тегами, которые будет работать только в пределах этого блока и не нарушать общие стили страницы, например, как при просмотре почты - внутри письма может быть html контент, но он не работает на всей странице?

Если это возможно, как это сделать? Какой лучший путь для реализации?

Comment: iframe. . . . .

Comment: Shadow Dom (https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom) - не подходит ?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант `iframe`:

```html
<iframe src="https://gazeta.ru" width="550" height="150">
```

Вариант `object`:

```html
<object data="https://gazeta.ru" width="550" height="150"></object>
```

Вариант `embed`:

```html
<embed src="https://gazeta.ru" width=550 height=150 />
```